# Underscore Js _.each used with ejs error

Tags: node.js, underscore.js, ejs, underscore.js-templating

I am trying to display the value in array using _.each and EJS dynamically. I am getting the values when i do it manually,but getting **Unexpected token ; error while using _.each loop**.

Here is the code

```
`<% _.each(pro,function(prof) { %>
    alert(prof.Name);
 <% } %>`

pro = {[object Object],[object Object]}
```

when i do it manually,i get the output.

i.e.

```
`<%= pro[0].Name %>`
```

Need help! Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: you can't use underscore.js methods in your ejs files. underscore.js is loaded per module and is used in module's scope. Try wrapping _.each invokation in some printStatements() method and then call that method from within ejs file.

Answer (score 0):

You seem have missed a parentheses here:

```
<% }) %>`
```

Beyond that, I'm not sure you can use underscore inside your EJS templates.

Try using a regular `for`.

```
<% for(var i=0; i<prof.length; i++) {%>
  <li><%= prof[i] %></li>
<% } %>
```